# Why array passed to function is null?

Tags: c++

I know this is basic, but I think of this logically, and don't get this.

```
char *me[] = {0};
getHardwareEEprom(me);
printf("**%s\n", me[0]); // null 

void EEprom::getHardwareEEprom(char *eeprom[])
{
     char *EEPROM[]={"A4", "B3", "C=AB", "if(C7)", "(C)", NULL};
     eeprom = EEPROM; // set the address for the data array
}
```

1. `me` is a pointer that points to some place
2. its passed to this function, where it gets an address of some array in memory
3. `me` holds now the address for the array `EEPROM`
4. printing the first word of it show null

No matter how much I read, I just do not seems to get this thing.

Comment: Please read [ask] and remove `*` from the first line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing particularly special going on here.

You are changing what the function parameter `eeprom` is assigned to, that's all. And that assignment is valid for the lifetime of `EEPROM`.

But that change is not reflected in the caller (C++ is a pass by value language). So `me` in the caller stays as it was.

It would have been a different matter entirely had the function parameter `eeprom` had been passed by *reference*.

Comment: Thank you. How would you pass it by reference ?

Comment: Use one of these thingies `&` in the function parameter list.

Comment: Take care, this assignment is not valid, even if `EEPROM` was not deallocated. Your global copy of `eeprom` will not get the new address value.

Answer (score 2):

`char *EEPROM[]={"A4", "B3", "C=AB", "if(C7)", "(C)", NULL};` has automatic storage, stack allocated.

It lives until the function `getHardwareEEprom` ends and return to the caller.

Also `char *eeprom[]` has local scope, so modification to it inside function is not reflected to the pointer passed.

At the end, a C style solution can be

```
#include<stdio.h>

void getHardwareEEprom(char ***eeprom)
{
     static char *EEPROM[]={"A4", "B3", "C=AB", "if(C7)", "(C)", NULL};
     *eeprom = EEPROM; // set the address for the data array
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t i=0;
    char **me = {0};
    getHardwareEEprom(&me);
    while(me[i] != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", me[i]);

        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. that makes it clear. So is there any way to get the same functionality ?

Comment: Well, a lot of. Finally is [tag:c++] so you can `new` members of passed pointer or simply make the the `EEPROM` array `static` or `global`

Comment: I don't think this is actually UB. Do check again, and downvote my answer if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes, you right 'cause `char *eeprom[]` has local scope too. My bad ;)

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning a local variable, `EEPROM`, which goes out of scope when the function returns, so it's not valid when you call `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

Arguments are passed by value in C. The statement

```
eeprom = EEPROM;
```

has no effect in the calling function.

Answer (score 1):

First, this is not C but C++ (C does not have class, check `EEprom::`).

Also, take care of the scope of your variables. Here, `char *EEPROM[]={"A4", "B3", "C=AB", "if(C7)", "(C)", NULL};` is defined and memory is allocated inside your function, so when the function will return, the memory will be deallocated.

Another problem here is that you can not set the address of your parameter without returning it : when using argument by reference, your function gets a copy of your pointer address. Then, in your example, your function's local copy of `eeprom` change its address to the address of `EEPROM`. But the global copy (the one used to call the function) does not take the new address, to bypass this, your function could return the proper address :

```
char **foo(void)
{
    char **EEPROM = NULL;
    // Here you should allocate your memory with malloc and fill the array with your data

    return EEPROM;
}

char **bar = foo();
```

This way, you solve your 2 problems : you do not use a pointer to deallocated memory, and you get a valid pointer to your data outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

When your are calling `getHardwareEEprom(me);`, you are passing the address of `me` to the function, and that address is pointed by `eeprom` in your function.

But as soon as you do `eeprom = EEPROM;`  in your function, there is NO connection left now. And, `eeprom` points to somewhere else entirely, i.e. it points to the address of `EEPROM` array. Thus `eeprom` and `me` have no relation anymore.

To change the content of `me` like you are expecting, you have to do:

```
eeprom[0] = "test"; // OR
*eeprom = "test";
```